# Javascript regex to check if string is a valid number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want this Regex to match these valid number formats:

```
"^[+,-]?[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)?$"

1. [+,-]? : + or - optional
2. [0-9]* : as many 0 to 9 number
3. (\\.[0-9]*)? : . and as many 0 to 9 number optional
```

I am almost there, because I get the following as desired:

```
"99999"  -> true
"99"     -> true
"9.9"    -> true
"9.999"  -> true
"9."     -> true
"-9."    -> true
"+9.9"   -> true
"-0.9"   -> true
"-.9"    -> true
```

However, the following case should be false but the Regex outputs true:

```
"+."      
"."
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: You need to replace the `[0-9]*` patterns with `[0-9]+`, but that will require a digit before the `.` always, so you need alternatives for `\.[0-9]+` and `[0-9]+\.`.

Comment: comma won't come here `[+,-]?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?![+-]?\.$)[+-]?\d*(?:\.\d*)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO5zI3/9)

Comment: what does the (?=.*?\d) do ??  It gives true for "=9" which is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[+-]?(?:\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH7wO3/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:\+|\+\.|\.)$)[+,-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/3

`escape \ if required`

```
^(?!(?:\\+|\\+\\.|\\.)$)[+,-]?[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)?$
```

A `negative lookahead` will make sure `+.`,`+`,`.` dont match.